# ScintillaNET problems in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, scintilla

Im using ScintillaNET and i want syntax highlighting.
I Cant seem to figure it out :(

i have tried:

```
Scintilla.Lexing.Lexer = ScintillaNet.Lexer.Php
Scintilla.Lexing.LoadLexerLibrary(ScintillaNet.Lexer.Php)
Scintilla.Lexing.LexerName = "php"
Scintilla.ConfigurationManager.Language = "phpscript"
Scintilla.ConfigurationManager.Language = "php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in form load.

Scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Language = "vbscript" ' Change vbscript to your language.

And by the way, you have to look at the supported languages for scintilla, the language you want may not be supported.

Comment: I did test this and, in my case, it's working with Scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Language = "bash" but not with Scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Language = "php", although php is supported as far as I understand...(https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11102232/)